# Show that if any $z$ is any $n$'th root of $1$ other than $1$ itself

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Show that if any $z$ is any $n$'th root of $1$ other than $1$ itself, then $1+z+z^{2}+...+z^{n-1}$=$0$
The only thing I can take from this is making  $1+z+z^{2}+...+z^{n-1}$=($\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$)
 Other than what I did, I do not understand. Unless I set ($\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$)=$0$ and solve
 Need  some help

Answer (score 2):

Now you are given that $z^n=1$, so your fraction is $0$

Comment: huh? Not following you unless. i do not see $z^{n}$=$1$ anywhere here

Comment: Your $z$ is an $n$-th root of $1$, so $z^n = 1$ by definition.

Comment: ok so that is all I have to say to show that?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of an $n^{th}$ root.